# Stored procedure from VBA Excel not running

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I'm calling from VBA a stored procedure from a PC and it is working okay. In another PC and different user it is not working. A single query though, it is working in both PCs.

I'm calling the stored procedure as follows:

```vb
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

' Connection string for accessing MS SQL database
ConnectionString = <Connection details>

' Opens connection to the database
cnn.Open ConnectionString
' Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; The stored procedure normally runs for around 20 min
cnn.CommandTimeout = 2400

' Process execution
StrQuery = "exec [00_Main] @date = '01/31/2018' "
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
rst.Close
```

I'm guessing that I have an error message when executing the stored procedure, but I don't know how to capture it.

I tried the following, but I don't get anything as an output

```vb
' Process execution
StrQuery = "exec [00_Main] @date = '01/31/2018' "
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
Debug.Print rst.Fields.Count
Debug.Print rst.RecordCount
Debug.Print rst
rst.Close
```

When I run the stored procedure in SQL Management studio I just get output messages as the stored procedure just updates tables. Like:

```vb
(29145907 rows affected)
(330527 rows affected)
```

I tried also adding Error Information following link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb), but the process runs without giving me any error. Like:

```vb
' Process execution
DateSelection = Sheets("STB Check").Range("F1")
'StrQuery = "exec [00_Main] @date = '" & DateSelection & "' "
StrQuery = "exec [00_Main] @date = '01/31/2018' "
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

Done:
rst.Close
Exit Sub

AdoError:

  Dim errLoop As Error
  Dim strError As String

  i = 1

' Process
 StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "VB Error # " & Str(Err.Number)
 StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Generated by " & Err.Source
 StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & Err.Description

' Enumerate Errors collection and display properties of
' each Error object.
 Set Errs1 = cnn.Errors
 For Each errLoop In Errs1
      With errLoop
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "Error #" & i & ":"
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   ADO Error   #" & .Number
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & .Description
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Source       " & .Source
        i = i + 1
   End With
Next

  MsgBox StrTmp

  ' Clean up Gracefully

  On Error Resume Next
  GoTo Done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working" when you run it from the second PC?  Also, what happens when the users swap PC's?

Comment: The PC I don't think it maters, I think it is only the user. What I mean as not working is that I don't see the tables updated after I run the stored procedure. Also, it normally takes 20 min to run and it this other PC/User it takes a second.

Comment: My guess is you have an error. You don't have that dreaded ON ERROR RESUME NEXT do you? Put in a break point and debug your execution.

Comment: Try checking the `Connection.Errors` collection after it fails - eg see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb

Comment: Does the SP specify `set nocount on;`? Forgetting to add that has caused me problems before.. Also what is the data type of the parameter, and does it not need to be a parameter in your ADODB query too?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've added the code as per the link (see edited detail above) but the it ran through without any error. Did I used the code incorrectly?

Comment: Umm, your connection is named `cnn` so there's not much use in checking errors on `Conn1` - there's no way that ran without errors.  Where is your error handling code?  It looks like you have some set up, but there's no `On Error...` there.

Comment: MathieuGuindon, I've tried StrQuery = "set nocount on exec [00_Main] @date = '01/31/2018' " as you suggested, but didn't make any difference. The parameter is '01/31/2018'.

Comment: no, `set nocount on;` would be an instruction *inside the stored procedure*, not on the ADO command.

Comment: If your SP returns no records, you can't do anything with that recordset - you can use use the connection.execute method.

Comment: stored procedures are permissioned, have you checked that both users have the same (execute) access?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've replaced O'n Error Resume Next', for 'On Error GoTo AdoError' and it seems like it is capturing an error, but it stops in line 'Set Errs1 = cnn.Errors' with a Type mistmatch ?-(

Comment: @SMeaden, I think you might be right. The answer from Mathieu gave me an error message that might help to investigate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use proper parameterization, and treat dates as `Date`, not as strings.

Instead of running that straight off `ADODB.Recordset`, use an `ADODB.Command`; set the command text to just the name of the stored procedure, and add an `ADODB.Parameter` to its `Parameters` collection, providing the cell value (after validating that `IsDate` returns `True` for that cell value) - [like on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-and-createparameter-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017):

```vb
Dim theDate As Date
theDate = Sheets("STB Check").Range("F1").Value

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "[00_Main]"

Dim dateParam As ADODB.Parameter
Set dateParam = cmd.CreateParameter("date", adDate, adParamInput)
dateParam.Value = theDate

cmd.Parameters.Append dateParam

Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: Thanks, like this I get an error message 'access to remote server is denied because no login-mapping exist'. I think this gives me something to dig into

Comment: @Selrac yup, looks like a trivial permission issue ;-)